# grails mockFor closure wierdness

Tags: grails, groovy

Right,

so when I set up my mock using the testing plugin's mockFor method, I expect a method
that returns null. If I do

```
myControl.demand.theMethod {return null}
```

in the debugger, the value that I set the 'theMethod' call result to is some closure in the debugger.

If I do

```
myControl.demand.theMethod {->return null}
```

the value is null, as expected.

I dont understand the difference....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope I word this right

In the groovy documentation  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures  it states that "A Closure without -> , i.e. {} , is a Closure with one argument that is implicitly named as 'it'."  .... "In some cases, you need to construct a Closure with zero arguments, e.g. using GString for templating, defining EMC Property etc. You have to explicity define your Closure as { -> } instead of just { }"

In essence, your mock was trying to use 'return' as an argument.  You need the -> to say "I have no parameters to pass"  and then put what you want it to return on the right side of the arrow

Comment: Ahhhh facepalm....the { return } implies one argument, the method i was mocking required 0 args, so {->} is correct....thanx