# Throw an exception from a grails mock method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, mocking

On a Grails' controller unit test (more specifically a Spock `ControllerSpec`), I'd like to check the behavior of the tested method when a collaborator throws and exception.

I'm using the mockFor utility (either from Spock's UnitSpec or Grails' GrailsUnitTestMixin) to specify my demands for such exception-throwing method in the test, like this:

```
@TestFor(TestController)
class TestControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def "throwing and exception from a mock method should make the test fail"() {
        setup:
        def serviceMock = mockFor(TestService)
        serviceMock.demand.exceptionThrowingMethod() { throw new Exception() }
        controller.testService = serviceMock.createMock()

        when:
        controller.triggerException()

        then:
        thrown(Exception)
    }
}
```

So, inside `triggerException` I invoke `exceptionThrowingMethod`, like this:

```
class TestController {

    def testService

    def triggerException() {
        testService.exceptionThrowingMethod()
    }
}
```

But the test is failing like:

> Expected exception java.lang.Exception, but no exception was thrown

I debugged the excecution and the exception is not beign thrown, the invokation of `exceptionThrowingMethod` surprisingly returns a Closure. Nevermind adding the `throws` declaration to the method's signature, won't work either.

I thought this was related to Spock, but I tried a simliar test using just grails' test mixins and got the same result. This was my attempt:

```
@TestFor(TestController)
class TestControllerTests {

    void testException() {
        def serviceMock = mockFor(TestService)
        serviceMock.demand.exceptionThrowingMethod() { throw new Exception() }
        controller.testService = serviceMock.createMock()

        shouldFail(Exception) {
            controller.triggerException()
        }
    }
}
```

Do you find anything wrong in my code?

I couldn't find at any point in Grails' docs how to demand an exception to be thrown, so the above code sounded natural to me.

I also find it suspicious not finding anything related by googling, so maybe I'm trying to do the wrong thing regarding testing.

Isn't this a common case in testing? You mock some method's deterministic behaviour in a specific scenario, and then test the expected behaviour of the method under test when such a scenario occurs. Throwing an exception looked like a valid scenario to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that making the `demand` closure niladic (i.e. having no implicit `it` argument, with an explicit `->`) [does the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922947/grails-mockfor-closure-wierdness):

```
serviceMock.demand.exceptionThrowingMethod {-> throw new Exception() }
```

---

**Update**: you may also use Groovy's native `MockFor` class, which, it seems, doesn't require this closure weirdness:

```
@TestFor(TestController)
class TestControllerTests {

    void testException() {
        def mock = new MockFor(TestService)
        mock.demand.exceptionThrowingMethod { throw new Exception() }
        controller.testService = mock.proxyInstance()

        shouldFail { controller.triggerException() }
        mock.verify(controller.testService)
    }
}
```

Notice that when not using `mock.use`, `mock.verify` has to be used in order to verify the mock constraints (i.e. that `exceptionThrowingMethod` was called once).

Comment: BTW, I'd also like to know if this is a common case in testing :D

Comment: @doelleri Maybe ["nullary"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity#Nullary) is a more common synonym, but I think "niladic" sounds much better!

Comment: Your answer was very useful. However, if the question you linked to would have been correctly entitled I could have found it and not polluted SO with a duplicate. Nevermind it was written by a >27k reputation user...

Comment: @Esteban Well, sometimes it's not easy to correctly describe or entitle questions; basically because you may not know what is going wrong. What was the correct title for the question I linked? After all, it _was_ kind of a weird thing with closures and the mockFor method. If you feel that now your question is redundant, don't; I think some redundancy is to be expected here, as the same problems can appear in different contexts. Your question could very well help someone with that problem later. You might consider adding something like "mocked method returns a closure" in the title though :)